# Код на localhost работает как надо, а с файла index.html запускается долго и отображается неправильно

Tags: localhost

собственно, в visual studio открываю через сборщик gulp, все отлично на всех браузерах, а когда открываю с архива, долго грузит и отображается неправильно, нет иконок, и стили некоторые отображаются неправильно. В чем может быть неполадка?
[тут](https://github.com/affectal/Re-point) архив

Comment: Проверьте консоль (браузера), возможно там есть сообщения типа: "Не могу получить файл по URL"

Comment: так и есть, не видит  путь до иконок

Comment: а почему через VS видит? как исправить проблему?